# Why is the diff of two datetime objects so?

Tags: python, datetime

```
datetime1 = '2020-08-19 10:13:19'
datetime2 = '2020-08-19 19:00:00'

diff = datetime1 - datetime2
```

The diff is a timedelta object, with:

```
diff.days = -1
diff.seconds = 54766 = 15.22 hours
```

There are only about 9 hours diff between the two datetimes. Why does it show the number of days is '1' and 15.22 hours? How to understand the diff of two datetimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, the difference between two datetime objects has a negative number of days, and a positive number of hours.

```
import datetime
datetime1 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-08-19 10:13:19')
datetime2 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-08-19 19:00:00')

print(datetime1 - datetime2)
-1 day, 15:13:19

# divide by timedelta() (with argument of hours, minutes, seconds, etc.
print((datetime1 - datetime2) / datetime.timedelta(hours=1)) # in hours
-8.778055555555556
```

Here is an interesting interview with the core developer who maintains date / time in CPython:  https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/271/unlock-the-mysteries-of-time-pythons-datetime-that-is

UPDATE

You can calculate time difference in minutes, or days, or other units, by supplying a different parameter to `.timedelta()`:

```
print((datetime1 - datetime2) / datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)) # in minutes
-526.68

print((datetime1 - datetime2) / datetime.timedelta(days=1)) # in days
-0.3658
```

Comment: Doesn't answer question.

Comment: @jsmart, what does the -8.778 means? Is the actual time diff of the two objects?

Comment: Hi, the -8.778 is the time difference in hours; note the denominator is `timedelta(hours=1)`.  If you wanted the time difference in minutes or days, you would make that `.timedelta(minutes=1)` or `.timedelta(days=1)`

Answer (score 2):

If you subtract the earlier datetime from the later datetime, you get a positive timedelta, as one would expect.

The other way around, you get a negative timedelata in the unusual format.
But when you calculate `-1 day + 15 hours = -24 hours + 15 hours = -9 hours`, the result is correct.
Of course, doing this calculation manually is not what we want.

So, either avoid subtracting a later datetime from an earlier datetime:

```
# to get an absolute timedelta
if datetime2 > datetime1:
    print(datetime2 - datetime1)
else:
    print(datetime1 - datetime2)
```

Or use `.total_seconds()`:

```
print((datetime1 - datetime2).total_seconds())
-31601.0
print((datetime2 - datetime1).total_seconds())
31601.0
```